# Would one consider this to be weak convergence?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Suppose we have a matrix $\Sigma_p \in \mathbb{M}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ with coefficients depending on $p$. Hence we may form a sequence $\{ \Sigma_p \}_{p=1}^{\infty} \subseteq \mathbb{M}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$. Now let $\varphi \in \mathscr{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ be a smooth function and consider $$T_p : = \varphi(\left| \Sigma_p \right|),$$ where $\left| \cdot \right|$ denotes the determinant function. If $T_p \to T$, where $T = \varphi(\left| \Sigma \right|)$, would we say that this convergence is in the weak-topology?

Answer (score 1):

For any space $X$ with a functions $f_i: X \to Y$ , where $Y$ has a topology, we say that $(x_n) \subseteq X$ converges weakly to $x$ w.r.t. the $f_i$, iff $\forall i: f_i(x_n) \to f_i(x)$. So you have this situation for the function $\phi(| \cdot |)$, which is a sort of pseudonorm. It's not standard though.

But in this matrix case, it's more common to consider the weak topology to be the coordinatewise topology, so the weak convergence based on the functions $\pi_{i,j}: \Sigma \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\pi_{i,j}(\Sigma) = \Sigma_{i,j}$, for all $(i,j), 1 \le i,j \le n$.